# A problem of the possibility to extend by Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X=L^1[0,1]$ and $Y=C[0,1]$, $Y\subseteq X$. Choose $x_0\in(0,1)$ and let $l(f)=f(x_0)$ for $f\in Y$. Is it possible to extend $l$ to a bounded linear functional on $X$?

My attempt: Choose the subadditive function $p$ as $p(f)=\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$. Then $|l(f)|\leq  p(f)=\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$. Then by Complex Hahn-Banach Theorem, $l$ can be extend to $L:X\to\Bbb C$. But I can't show the "bounded" part: All I have is $\Vert L\Vert=\sup\limits_{\Vert f \Vert=1}|L(f)|\leq \sup\limits_{\Vert f \Vert=1}p(f)=\sup\limits_{\Vert f \Vert=1}\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$. So is the answer to the question no? Or should I try another "$p$"?

Comment: Why not construct it directly using an approximate identity?

Comment: @Dunham Since we haven't taught this

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment.  There is no extension since $l$ itself is not even bounded on $Y$.

Comment: @Dunham How to see so?

Comment: Consider increasingly narrower triangular functions centered at $x_0$ with height 1. $l$ will always be 1, but the 1-norm converges to 0.